# Is it correct to say that $\log_2 0=-\infty$?

Tags: logarithms

The logarithm is not defined at $x=0$, because it tends to $-\infty$ as x tends to 0 from above. But is it nevetheless correct to say that
$$
\log_2(0)=-\infty?
$$

Or is it better to say/ write
$$
\log_2(0)=\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\log_2(x)=-\infty
$$

Comment: No.$\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

It is correct to say that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \log(x) = -\infty$. That is, $\log x$ *tends toward* $-\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$.

However, $\log(0)$ is **not equal** to $-\infty$, because, as you say, $\log(x)$ is undefined at $x = 0$.

Comment: What's with something like $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log_2 x_n$ if $x_n=0\forall n\geq 1$?

Comment: That limit is indeterminate.

Comment: Hm, but in a book is it said that this is $-\infty$.

Comment: See Wolfram [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28n+to+infty%29+%281%2Fn%29+log%280%29) Note that indeterminate isn't equivalent to "undefined" nor to "limit does not exist."

Comment: Ok. I am not familiar with this expression. How can the book then claim that it is $-\infty$?

Comment: And Wolfram says that $\log_2(0)=-\infty$... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2%280%29

Comment: @mathfemi: Was it a physics book?

Answer (score 1):

as you said, it is not defined at 0. But, (here I wave my hand), it is ok to think it is $-\infty$ when you work in limit sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could *define* an element called $-\infty$ and then define, for example, $\ln: \left [{0..+\infty}\right) \to \mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. There are maths that do this, and the codomain is called the "extended reals". But there's no point in doing so here because $-\infty$ wouldn't have the properties of regular numbers in terms of multiplication, subtraction etc.  Also, it would be confusing, because you'd be using $\ln$ as a different function than other people. So don't do it.